# Java JDK 8/11/17 All Crashing on MacOS Monterey (12.0.1)

Tags: mac, crash, java, monterey

It appears using Oracle SQL Developer will eventually crash Java on JDK 8, 11 or 17 when using macOS Monterey (12.0.1). While I've thought it was working it will crash eventually as reported now by several users.  And what appears to be crashing is Java itself.  I don't even think it is a specific Oracle SQL Developer issue.  Has anyone else been having their Java applications fail on Monterey (12.0.1) and come up with a workaround or settings change that works?  P.S. This is on Intel based Macs upgraded to Monterey.  I'm not sure how M1 machines are doing.

Comment: Both Eclipse and all my Java apps work fine on Monterey using Java 17 so I would say this is more likely SQL Developer doing some particular operation that is hitting a bug in the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to start up Oracle SQL Developer v21.2.1 with JDK 17.0.1 and JDK 8_311 and JDK 11.0.13

But I get a warning popup as below when I do it with JDK 17.0.1 - but it is still starting up fine:

[image]

Comment: SQL developer download page https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html says it only works with Java 8 or 11

Comment: Yes, the pop up say that too - but I was able to start up with JDK 17 - if everything works with 17 I don’t know.